# Android L shadow on overflow menu glitch

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm porting my application to the new Android L. The app works fine except for the Overflow menu that have a glitch as you can see from the photos.

[image]
[image]

Anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed for a future Android release, but in the meantime you can work around the issue by using a non-opaque popup menu background. The default background in Material is a 2dp rounded rectangle, which will work fine, but if you absolutely need a custom background then you can do something like:

res/drawable/my_menu_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/my_color" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I'm using the Holo theme and I just want to make a menu with white background. So how I can fix the glitch?

Comment: You can a) use a non-opaque menu background or b) not use a custom background. The default background under Material theme is already correctly colored, there is really no need for you to customize it.

Comment: Ok, I think that the best move will be updating the application theme to Material, taking advantage from the new features :)